# Show only unmatched values of two columns in third column of table in an oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want to create a `stored procedure` where I want to check the below condition.

[image: IMG1]

In above two columns, `RJ_SAPID` and `RJ_COLO_SAPID` in first row the value `I-GJ-JMLU-ENB-6011` is common.

So except that value i want to show the other two values in third column by using stored procedure.

I tried using `REPLACE` function but couldn't succeed. Below is the code

```
SELECT REPLACE(RJ_SAPID, RJ_COLO_SAPID, '') FROM NE_STRUCTURES;
```

Please suggest how to proceed.

**table definition**

```html
OBJECTID                       NUMBER        
RJ_SAPID                       VARCHAR2(20)  
RJ_COLO_SAPID                  VARCHAR2(200) 
RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID           VARCHAR2(30)  
STRUCTURE_NAME                 VARCHAR2(200) 
INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE          VARCHAR2(4)   
RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE       VARCHAR2(20)  
RJ_SITE_NAME                   VARCHAR2(200) 
RJ_SITE_ADDRESS                VARCHAR2(500) 
RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE              VARCHAR2(20)  
TYPE_NAME                      VARCHAR2(20)  
RJ_LAST_MODIFIED_BY            VARCHAR2(50)  
RJ_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE          DATE          
RJ_STATUS                      VARCHAR2(200) 
RJ_CITY_CODE                   VARCHAR2(10)  
RJ_R4G_STATE_CODE              VARCHAR2(10)  
RJ_DISTRICT_CODE               VARCHAR2(20)  
RJ_TALUK_CODE                  VARCHAR2(20)  
RJ_JC_CODE                     VARCHAR2(20)  
RJ_JIOPOINT_SAPCODE            VARCHAR2(20)  
RJ_COMPANY_CODE_1              VARCHAR2(20)  
RJ_COMPANY_CODE_2              VARCHAR2(20)  
NE_STATUS                      VARCHAR2(20)
```

Comment: `SELECT RJ_SAPID, RJ_COLO_SAPID, REPLACE(RJ_COLO_SAPID, RJ_SAPID, '') AS ThirdColumn FROM NE_STRUCTURES`

Comment: @Arulkumar:Thanks Mate, but `,` is coming before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `REPLACE(RJ_COLO_SAPID, RJ_SAPID, '')` and for leading comma, use `LTRIM`

```
SELECT RJ_SAPID, RJ_COLO_SAPID, 
       REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(RJ_COLO_SAPID, RJ_SAPID, ''), ','), ','), ',,', '') AS ThirdColumn 
FROM NE_STRUCTURES
```

Comment: yes its working for ltrim, but in last also comma is coming

Comment: So, in your second row, are you expect the output with comma as `I-GJ-NKTR-AGL-6002,IGJ-NKTR-AGL-6002` or instead of comma a empty space as `I-GJ-NKTR-AGL-6002 IGJ-NKTR-AGL-6002` ?

Comment: nope, the output for rows is coming as `I-GJ-NKTR-XNB-9022,`

Comment: did u got it mate ?

Comment: Then you can use RTRIM too `RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(RJ_COLO_SAPID, RJ_SAPID, ''), ','), ',')`

Comment: Yup, its working now.. Can we create a procedure of it and insert the `ThirdColumn` in `RJ_SAPID` columns. ?? I will accept this answer

Comment: `RJ_SAPID` data size is `VARCHAR2(20)`, if the `ThirdColumn` size is not exceed 20 characters you can update in the `RJ_SAPID`. Also if there are some entries already there with `RJ_SAPID`, `RJ_COLO_SAPID`, you may update the value and not insert

Comment: No, so in that case if it exceeds further than 20, we can break that too as we replaced it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194435/discussion-between-arulkumar-and-b-n).

Comment: sorry, was breaking my fast.. so did u got my question as to what exactly I want?

Comment: I have answered your actual question, if you have anything new, please post a new question.

Comment: are u here ? need one help related to this

Answer (score 1):

Just switch your arguments and you will be fine:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RJ_COLO_SAPID, RJ_SAPID, '') FROM NE_STRUCTURES
```

And if you want to strip unneeded commata use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(RJ_COLO_SAPID, RJ_SAPID, ''),'^,+|,+$|(,),+','\1') FROM NE_STRUCTURES
```

Comment: In this way you may get a comma at the beginning or at the end or a double comma somewhere in the middle